# Can unregistered users bypass suspension?

Tags: discussion, support

Can unregistered users bypass suspension, is it uncontrollable by admins?

Comment: Yes.  Not completely.

Comment: There are some internal tools for this purpose that we're using; they're obviously not overly effective, but we're working on changing that. Use offensive flags judiciously, please.

Comment: Please only use the [meta-tag:bug] tag for actual software bugs. This is indeed an issue, but a social one that as developers we can't fix just by writing/updating code.

Answer (score 6):

The fact is that there is no real recourse for preventing people from registering new accounts. Or generating new unregistered accounts

This is the internet, it's painfully easy to superficially change your identity. Requiring registration fixes nothing here as you can get an open id as easy as you can get a new email address. IP bans are relatively easy to avoid as well.

SE is hard at work developing solutions to quickly identify and even preemptively block trolls from showing up continuously. But the fact is, if there is a determined human being on the other end it's going to be hard for *any* automated mechanism to stop them completely.

Comment: quarantine has been proposed as a measure for screening new users: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2875/7036